# Explicit solution of specific 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can the equation $a'' = 1 - a^{-3}$ be solved in closed form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the substitution $v=a'$. Then since

$$a'' = \frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{dv}{da}\frac{da}{dx} = v \frac{dv}{da}$$

we can write the ODE as

$$v \frac{dv}{da} =  1-a^{-3}.$$

This is separable and so it can be integrated:

$$v(a) = \pm \sqrt{2a+a^{-2} +C}.$$

Then, since $a'=v(a)$ we can finally solve

$$a' = \pm \sqrt{2a+a^{-2}+C},$$

which is separable.  Admittedly the integral does not look promising.

This idea for substitution comes from [here](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/nonlineareq/nonlineareq.html).

Comment: Ah yes, thank you, now I remember that's how this goes. The integral indeed doesn't look too good -- I think I'll settle for "no" as an answer to my question.